# spring boot monitoring in practice

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

spring boot actuator exposes `/metrics` endpoints. but it produces a value only when combined with monitoring tools, diagrams, alerting etc. so:

does spring-boot provides support for push-based metrics collection? if so, what's the tool?
or maybe there are some production-ready tools (with service registry etc) that work with spring-boot in pull-based manner and actually use the `/metrics` endpoint? for example prometheus perfectly discovers all EC2 instances but is incompatible with spring boot metrics (counters and format).

so is there any real world, production ready tools that can be used out of the box? or we're not there yet?

Comment: Why use the endpoint? Register a proper exporter to export to what you want... There are several implementations already out-of-the-box...

Comment: i don't have to use the endpoint. just mentioned it because that's the default. what implementations will export jvm stats, endpoint status code stats, hystrix data and basically all the metrics collected by spring-boot?

Comment: I just saw that there is an example of reporting spring boot application metrics to Prometheus https://github.com/thomasdarimont/spring-boot-prometheus-example.

Comment: I suggest a read of [the reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html) especially [this section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-metrics.html#production-ready-metric-writers)

Comment: yes, i know there is an api to export it. my question is: isn't there any ready to use, out of the box solution? something that i can import and enable with with 1 annotation and 3 config options

Comment: Have you looked at [Spring Boot Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin)